# Multiple conditions to generate a string within a Map function

Tags: javascript, loops, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I am storing an array that looks like:

```
let arr = [
  {
   name: "James",
   age: 24
  },
   name: "Patrick", 
   age: 20
  },
  {
   name: "John",
   age: 23
  }
];
```

I am trying to get a string that will look like:

```
Hi James, Patrick and John
        ^          ^
        |          |
      Comma       And
```

Adding a `,` (comma) after each name but not after the one before the last. and the word `And` right before the last word. I'm using Map:

```
arr.map((l,i) =>
  <span key={i}>
    {i < arr.length - 1 ? `${l.name}, ` :
     i === arr.length - 1 ? `and ${l.name}.` : ''}
  </span>)
```

I get:

```
James, Patrick, and John
              ^
              |
         This is Extra
```

Is there a beautiful and easy way to get such result? and a function that will be pure and work on all number of names within the array? Preferably with ES6.. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to leave out the Oxford comma?? ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
const names = arr.map((l,i) => html`<span key="${i}">${l.name}</span`);
const last = names.pop();
return names.length ? names.join(", ") + " and  " + last : last;
```

Don't use `map` for the parts that aren't the same for all items.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()` to do this

```js
let arr = [{
  name: "James",
  age: 24
}, {
  name: "Patrick",
  age: 20
}, {
  name: "John",
  age: 23
}];

var result = arr.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if ((i + 1) == (arr.length - 1)) {
    r += e.name;
  } else if ((i + 1) != arr.length) {
    r += e.name + ', ';
  } else {
    r += ' and ' + e.name;
  }
  return r;
}, 'Hi ');

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I think you should either add both separators before the name or both of them after the name, the current code is a bit hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
arr.map((l,i) =>
  if (i <arr.length-1) {
    if(i === arr.length-2) {
  <span key={i}>
     {`${l.name} `}
  </span>)
    } else {
  <span key={i}>
     {`${l.name}, `}
  </span>)        
    }
  } else {
  <span key={i}>
     `and ${l.name}.`
  </span>)
 }
```

Comment: The final condition `i === arr.length - 1` will always be `true`, so you can leave out that and the `: ''`

Answer (score 0):

you can try with below code

```
arr.map((l,i) =>
  <span key={i}>
    {i < arr.length - 1 && i !== arr.length - 2 ? `${l.name}, ` : ''}
    {i === arr.length - 2 ?  `${l.name} ` : ''}
    {i === arr.length - 1 ? `and ${l.name}.` : ''}
  </span>)
```